# Google docs viewer with files requiring authorization?

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-docs, documentviewer

Google docs viewer is quite good and easy to use tool. It only requires the file's 
path and renders the document. It also has a lot of additional features like choosing page, rotating, etc. 
However is there a way to set some authorization or additional headers to the call that gets the file ?

As far as I'm aware the document url is passed like that:

```
http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=<URL_OF_DOCUMENT>&embedded=true
```

I think this is very important because most of the files are secured ..

The ng-pdf-viewer for example has the option to receive an object as source:

```
 this.sourceObject = {
     src: this.document.documentLink, 
     httpHeaders: { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token }
 }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: could you give me a full example for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54535679/google-docs-viewer-with-files-requiring-authorization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution! The files should be loaded as blobs:

```
new Blob([new Uint8Array(response)], { type: 'application/pdf' })
```

and then the blobUrl should be passed to the viewer:

```
this.iframeSrc = `https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=${this.document.blobUrl}&embedded=true`;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Niether `URL.createObjectUrl()` nor data url's seem to work

Comment: @user3568791 does blob url works in google doc viewer?

Comment: Yes, it works. You have to explicitly set the type of the Blob to 'application/pdf'.

Comment: Did anyone actually get it to work besides the post author?

Comment: Not working!
When you put blob into javascript template string, you get:
https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=[object Blob]
If you convert this blob to URL using URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob), still google will not show it.